# Is there a standard way of determining the number of va_args?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm experimenting with variable arguments in C++, using [va_args](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_arg/).  The idea is useful, and is indeed something I've used a lot in C# via the params functionality.  One thing that frustrates me is the following excerpt regarding va_args, above:

> Notice also that va_arg does not determine either whether the retrieved argument is the last argument passed to the function (or even if it is an element past the end of that list).

I find it hard to believe that there is no way to programmatically determine the number of variable arguments passed to the function from within that function itself.  I would like to perform something like the following:

```
void fcn(int arg1 ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, arg1);

    int numRemainingParams = //function that returns number of remaining parameters
    for (int i=0; i<numRemainingParams; ++i)
    {
        //do stuff with params
    }
    va_end(argList);
}
```

To reiterate, the documentation above suggests that va_arg doesn't determine whether the retrieved arg is the last in the list.  But I feel this information must be accessible in some manner.

Is there a standard way of achieving this?

Comment: "But I feel this information must be accessible in some manner." -- Why? What reason do you have for believing that the documentation is incorrect?

Comment: There is, use variadic templates instead of variable argument lists  :-) `void f( ... )` becomes `template<class... T> void f( T&&... t )` and then the number of arguments is `sizeof...(T)`.

Comment: The reason I feel that the information should be accessible is because of the call stack.  At runtime, the parameters for the argument should be available at least there, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Kirby: yes, the parameters are on the call stack, but there's no way for the callee to know where the end of the parameters are, to get the number.  It's similar to the null terminator on C-style strings.

Comment: @Kirby Yes, but on a lot of implementations, there is no indication where it ends, and attempting to read past the last argument may (formally, it's undefined behaviour) give you a return address or different variable.

Comment: @Prætorian +1, but for completeness, that technically creates a different function for each number and types of arguments, and in each of those functions, the number of arguments is fixed. :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  So to be clear, the number of arguments for "normal" function calls is determined solely on the function signature?

Comment: It's not specified in the C++ standard, but on a lot of implementations, yes.

Comment: Excellent.  It appears that I had a misunderstanding of how this worked, but I'm glad to have it resolved through this discussion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I find it hard to believe that there is no way to programmatically determine the number of variable arguments passed to the function from within that function itself.

Nonetheless, it is true. C/C++ do not put markers on the end of the argument list, so the called function really does not know how many arguments it is receiving. If you need to mark the end of the arguments, you must do so yourself by putting some kind of marker at the end of the list.

The called function also has no idea of the types or sizes of the arguments provided. That's why `printf` and friends force you to specify the precise datatype of the value to interpolate into the format string, and also why you can crash a program by calling printf with a bad format string.

Note that parameter passing is specified by the ABI for a particular platform, not by the C++/C standards. However, the ABI must allow the C++/C standards to be implementable. For example, an ABI might want to pass parameters in registers for efficiency, but it might not be possible to implement va_args easily in that case. So it's possible that arguments are also shadowed on the stack. In almost no case is the stack marked to show the end of the argument list, though, since the C++/C standards don't require this information to be made available, and it would therefore be unnecessary overhead.

Comment: When the function is called, isn't the information about that function call placed on the call stack?  Can this information not be utilized?

Comment: @Kirby: the parameters are on the stack, but the _number_ of parameters is _not_ on the stack anywhere.  It's impossible (even in assembly) to read the stack and determine how many parameters were passed.

Comment: @Kirby, added another explanatory paragraph which might help (or it might be even more confusing).

Comment: Hard to decide between your answer and Dietmar's.  Both were informative, and very helpful to me.  I wish I could vote for two.  I ended up going with yours due to the added information.

Comment: Note that you *could* define a ABI where meta data about the parameters was put on the stack and therefore accessible to the callee, but I've never heard of one. I suspect it just costs too much to justify it's few uses.

Answer (score 6):

The way variable arguments work in C and C++ is relatively simple: the arguments are just pushed on the stack and it is the callee's responsibility to somewhat figure out what arguments there are. There is nothing in the standard which provides a way to determine the number of arguments. As a result, the number of arguments are determined by some context information, e.g., the number of elements referenced in a format string.

Individual compilers may know how many elements there are but there is no standard interface to obtain this value.

What you could do instead, however, is to use variadic templates: you can determine very detailed information on the arguments being passed to the function. The interface looks different and it may be necessary to channel the arguments into some sort of data structure but on the upside it would also work with types you cannot pass using variable arguments.

Comment: Excellent explanation.  If I could vote for two selected answers, I would choose yours as well.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. That's why variable arguments *are not safe*. They're a part of C, which lacks the expressiveness to achieve type safety for "convenient" variadic functions. You have to live with the fact that C contains constructions whose very correctness depends on *values* and not just on types. That's why it is an "unsafe language".

Don't use variable arguments in C++. It is a much stronger language that allows you to write equally convenient code that is safe.

Comment: A good answer should mention how to do this in the C++ way.  (chained operators or variadic templates)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Feel free to write one :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such way. If you have such a need, it's probably best to pack those function parameters in a `std::vector` or a similar collection which can be iterated.

Comment: Can't pass in random types that way

Comment: Why would you need that? If you need that, then it's a strong indication that something is wrong in your design of classes / data structures.

Comment: @Flavius I think what MooingDuck meant by *random types* was that a vector can only hold elements of the same type. `std::tuple` is much more applicable to doing what you're suggesting instead of a vector

Comment: @Prætorian +1. Indeed. Yet that approach is still a violation of orthogonality - he'll just toss multiple types of objects into one function, instead of **programming to the interface** (which he'd had to introduce).

Comment: @Flavius Depends on what your function is supposed to do. For instance, it is perfectly appropriate to *toss multiple types of objects into one function* for the `emplace` member function offered by standard containers.

Answer (score 1):

The variable argument list is a very old concept inherited from the C history of C++. It dates back to the time where C programmers usually had the generated assembler code in mind.

At that time the compiler did not check at all if the data you passed to a function when calling it matched the data types the function expected to receive. It was the programmer's responsibility to do that right. If, for example, the caller called the function with a `char` and the function expected an `int` the program crashed, although the compiler didn't complain.

Today's type checking prevents these errors, but with a variable argument list you go back to those old concepts including all risks. So, don't use it if you can avoid it somehow.

The fact that this concept is several decades old is probably the reason that it feels wrong compared to modern concepts of safe code.